# Inserting an element in a list without tail or head

Tags: c

I've got a little problem about an exercice which is supposed to explain how malloc works.

For starters, here's the header we have been given:

```
struct cell_m
{
    unsigned int magicnumber ;
        struct cell_m  *next ;
        void *userspacestart ;
        void *userspacestop  ;
};

typedef struct cell_m *liste_t ;
```

As you can see, I have only a next pointer so it's a simple chained list.
I am supposed to code a function to insert a `cell_m` inside a `liste_t` of `cell_m`.

There is one condition, the size of the cell_m that we want to insert must be smaller than the one we're currently at.
Here's my code of this function :

```
void insert(liste_t *list, liste_t cell)
{   
    liste_t *old_list = malloc(sizeof(liste_t*));

    if (sizeof((*list)->userspacestop) - (sizeof((*list)->userspacestart))
        >= (sizeof(cell->userspacestop)) - (sizeof(cell->userspacestart)))
        /*insert at the begining*/
    else
    {
        old_list = list;
        (*list) = (*list)->next;
        while ((*list)->next != NULL)
        {
            if (sizeof((*list)->userspacestop) - (sizeof((*list)->userspacestart))
                >= (sizeof(cell->userspacestop)) - (sizeof(cell->userspacestart)))
            {
                (*old_list)->next = cell;
                cell->next = (*list);
                break;
            }
            old_list = list;
            (*list) = (*list)->next;
        }
    }
}
```

A little explanation : I try to keep the last position of where I was in the list so I created an "***old_list***" variable to keep it.
At first, I tried to see if I can directly insert my cell at the beginning of the list. I'm not entirely sure what to put here so I put a comment for now.

Then, if it's not possible to insert it at the begining, I will move forward into my list and try to insert the element. (Then again, not entirely sure if the code for inserting is right)

Is this any good, or am I totally wrong with this code?

Comment: a) "supposed to explain how malloc works" - Then an important point is how a single new `cell` is initialized. Do you have the correct code for that, including the `malloc`? b) `void insert(liste_t *list, liste_t cell)` should rather be `void insert(liste_t *list, struct cell_m *cell)` to express more clearly that you are not inserting a list into the list but a cell.

Comment: `sizeof (void*)` is completely wrong here. Using a `char*` pointer instead should simplify the code a lot. (so would removing the typedef)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a code that has been given to me and i am not supposed to change it. I am not a big fan of this typedef either.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the first pointer points to the pointer that points to the list and the second argument is a pointer to the new element to insert, there is no reason to malloc() anything. You just need to find the place in the list where you want to insert.

---

```
struct cell_m {
    unsigned int magicnumber ;
        struct cell_m  *next ;
        char *userspacestart ; // character pointers allow pointer arithmetic
        char *userspacestop  ;
};

// typedefs only exist to confuse you
// typedef struct cell_m *liste_t ;

void insert(struct cell_m **head, struct cell_m *this)
{   
    for ( ;*head != NULL; head = &(*head)->next) {
        if (*head)->userspacestop - (*head)->userspacestart
            < this->userspacestop - this->userspacestart) break;

        }
    this->next = *head;
    *head = this;
}
```

---

You can of course do the same using `void *` pointers, but you will need a lot of casts to `char*` (or some other granularity) to get it working.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Just had to cast to char* as you said. Thank you very much.

Comment: *what* worked perfectly? Your original with the extra malloc() ? [downvoter: thanks for the downvote!]